# How do i query the database based on all the checkboxes checked by the user using php?

Tags: php, mysql

[An image of the table is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4QWR.png)I need to access all the checkboxes checked by the user and query database based on that.
For Example : if user checks honda and nissan in brands , 3-3.5 and 3.5-4 in price and 15-20 and 20-25 in mileage , i need to query the DB and give the results which satisfy all the above conditions. How do i implement this in php?
I have used Mysql database and it has 5 columns namely brand, mileage,fuel type , price and modelID(primary key).

```
<form method = "post">
<h1>BRAND</h1>
<font size="5">
<table cellspacing = "20px">
<tr>
<td>Hyundai<input type = "checkbox" name = "Hyundai"></input></td>
<td>Honda<input type = "checkbox" name = "Honda"></input></td>
<td>Ford<input type = "checkbox" name = "Ford"></input></td>
<td>Nissan<input type = "checkbox" name = "Nissan"></input></td>
<td>Volkswagen<input type = "checkbox" name = "Volkswagen"></input></td>
<td>Chevrolet<input type = "checkbox" name = "Chevrolet"></input></td>
<td>TATA Motors<input type = "checkbox" name = "TATA Motors"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</font>

<h1>MILEAGE(kmpl)</h1> 
<font size="5">
<table cellspacing = "20px">
<tr>
<td>15-20<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>20-25<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>25-30<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>30-35<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>35-40<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</font>


<h1>PRICE(in lakhs)</h1>
<font size="5">
<table cellspacing = "20px">
<tr>
<td>2 - 2.5<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>2.5 - 3<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>3 - 3.5<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>3.5 - 4<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>4 - 4.5<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>4.5 - 5<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>5 - 5.5<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</font>

<h1>FULE TYPE</h1>
<font size="5">
<table cellspacing = "20px">
<tr>
<td>PETROL<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>DIESEL<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
<td>CNG<input type = "checkbox"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
</font>
<input type = "submit" value = "GET ME RESULTS" ></input>
</form>
```

Comment: The form here is  almost completely irrelevant and you've given no clue as to how your database is organized. Please, post some details because this is impossible to answer without being psychic.

Comment: You write code. We're not here to do that for you. We help fix code you've written, not write code for you - that boils down to "do my job for me".

Comment: No. I , am not asking for the code. Sorry if i have conveyed the question like that. All i want to know is ,  how do i capture the checked boxes and query such that i select all the tuples where i have the attribute equal to checkbox name. for the above example i need to return the tuples where brand is honda or nissan , AND mileage is 15 - 20 kmpl or 20-25 kmpl ...so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you'll run into is the way your inputs are set up. If you write the checkbox HTML like this, it will be a lot easier to handle on the PHP side.

```
<td>Hyundai<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="Hyundai"></input></td>
<td>Honda<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="Honda"></input></td>
...etc.

<td>15-20<input type="checkbox" name="mileage[]" value="15-20"></input></td>
<td>20-25<input type="checkbox" name="mileage[]" value="20-25"></input></td>
...etc
```

This way, in the script that handles the form submission, you can refer to `$_POST['brand']`, for example, and get an array of all the selected brands.

An important thing when writing your query will be how to combine the ANDs and ORs. You should group your ORs in parentheses to make sure it functions the way you intend it to. For example:

```
WHERE (brand='Hyundai' OR brand='Honda') AND (mileage='15-20' OR mileage='20-25')
```

A cleaner way to do this is to use IN instead of a bunch of ORs

```
WHERE brand IN ('Hundai', 'Honda') AND mileage IN ('15-20', '20-25')
```

As for as the PHP code for how to write the interaction with your database, that really is too broad of a topic to answer, but you said you weren't asking for PHP code, so hopefully this will give you a general idea that will get you on your way.

Comment: After looking at the picture you attached showing the data in your database, you'll need to handle mileage and price differently, because you are looking for ranges of values rather than discrete values.